# how to set the default minDate in jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, mindate

It sets the minDate as I mentioned.. but I want to display the default mindate 1970-01-26 in jquery datepicker. here I have coded like this, but it didnt worked. Can anyone help me please..

```
$(function ()
{
  var oldMethod = $.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader;
  $.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader = function()
  {
   var html = $("<div />").html(oldMethod.apply(this,arguments));
   var monthselect = html.find(".ui-datepicker-month");
   monthselect.insertAfter(monthselect.next());
   return html.html();
  }
  $('input.datepicker_DOB').datepicker(
  {
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   minDate: '1970-01-26'
  });
});
```

and my html code is:

```
<input type="text" name="dob"  class="datepicker_DOB" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setDate`.

```
var defaultDateInput = new Date(1970, 01, 26);
$("input.datepicker_DOB").datepicker('setDate', defaultDateInput);
```

**OR**

```
var defaultDateInput = new Date(1970, 01, 26);
$("input.datepicker_DOB").val(defaultDateInput);
```

Comment: It working.. but I want the calender also start from the minDate instead of its displaying the today's date....Is it possible? If so, please help me...

Comment: thanks Dipesh Parmar.... but I actually looking for this only...yearRange: "-65y:-18y".. now i got it.. the calender displays from the minDate year... thanks for your rply..